# How to change text in sibling component in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I have an 'OutputBox' component and want to change the text being displayed in the component when I click a button.

I've read about props and state and i can't seem to get them working the way i need them too. I just started react-native and have a heavy background c++. I thought i could just declare a variable, 'text' in the 'OutputBox' component and then call a 'setOutputBoxText' function and change the 'text' var. Getters and Setters paradigm. I just cant wrap my head around how to use props to 'pass args' to components and the such.

```
export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
        <CustomButton 
          text="N"
          onPress={() => {
            OutputBox.setOutputBox('You head North');
            alert("You head North");
          }}
        />
         <OutputBox></OutputBox>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class CustomButton extends Component {
    render() {
        const { text, onPress} = this.props;
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle}
            onPress={() => onPress()}
          >
             <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{text}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}

class OutputBox extends Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props );
    var displayText = 'Hello Traveller';
  }
  setOutputBox( newText ){
    displayText = newText;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={ styles.outputBox }>
        <Text>{this.displayText}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I would expect to be able to do something similar to what i have, however i just keep getting a `typeError: OutputBox.setOutputBox` is not a function. I know this is the wrong paradigm for react-native. I can't seem to wrap my head around doing something like this with props and state.

UPDATE: I no longer get the error `typeError: OutputBox.setOutputBox is not a function`. Now, the `OutputBox` just doesn't display anything. How I do I get the `<Text/>` component of the `OutputBox` to change and display.

Comment: hmmm, this doesn't seem to make anything display in the ```OutputBox``` if i put an ```alert``` in and set it to the ```this.props.displayText``` it changes, however this still doesn't work for changing the text of ```OutputText```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct way to do it.

```
export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
      constructor( props ) {
         super( props );
        this.state={
          displayText : 'Hello Traveller',
          }
  }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
            <CustomButton 
              text="N"
              onPress={() => {
                this.setState({displayText:'You head North'})
              }}
            />
             <OutputBox text={this.state.displayText}/>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

class CustomButton extends Component {
        render() {
            const { text, onPress} = this.props;
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle}
                onPress={() => onPress()}
              >
                 <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{text}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        }
    }

    class OutputBox extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={ styles.outputBox }>
            <Text>{this.props.displayText}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
  }
```

Comment: i accepted the answer because it was correct, however my code was wrong and ended up deleting my ```OutputBox``` component and replacing it with a ```<Text>``` component. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the `OutputBox` component and put a `<Text>` component in there. I realized i didn't need the `OutputBox` component, since it's only purpose was to display text. This is what i ended up with

```
export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
      constructor( props ) {
         super( props );
        this.state={
          displayText : 'Hello Traveller',
          }
  }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
            <CustomButton 
              text="N"
              onPress={() => {
                this.setState({displayText:'You head North'})
              }}
            />
             <Text>{this.state.displayText}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

class CustomButton extends Component {
        render() {
            const { text, onPress} = this.props;
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle}
                onPress={() => onPress()}
              >
                 <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{text}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        }
    }
```